# Can't change table background color in the header in Microsoft Word 2011

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2011

Here we have 2 tables, one is in the header and another one is outside of the header. (content of the page)

As you can see, I can simply change the background color of each cell in the bottom table (via Borders & Shading > Shading properties), but if I try to do the same for another table in the header, as you can see, I only get a white background.

I don't know why this is happening, it was working some hours ago, but now, I'm stock with this.

I'm using Microsoft Word 2011 in Mac OS X 10.9.5.

[image]

Comment: Someone with enough reputation please update the question and add the image shown in the link.

Comment: Same question here ... Even if I save, close and reopen a file, some formattings changes :(

Comment: FWIW I cannot currently replicate this problem here, but can you work around by creating the table in the body, then copy/paste? Or does that fail in the same way?

Comment: Can you upload the document somewhere for testing?

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue. For the header you are trying to apply the shading to, click on the Header and Footer tab in the Ribbon menu bar and uncheck "Link to Previous" under the Options column.

Answer (score 0):

As document is not available i cant see the exact problem so  i can guide some steps you can try one of them may work.

1. Change the style of the header as some time font style  background. Color overwrites cell color
2. Try to check if any cell colour is not define on the cell
3. Save your current table colour design then try to change readymade design styles of table
4. Create a new blank document and try to design colour its header and if it works copy back to the document
5. As you told previously it was worling then may be some style or design is auto saved by word Copy and then paste  the whole document into fresh new documents and then try to change the header styles or designs
6. Fill with paragraph color to the header
7. Remove header if it's not indexed ( you are not using index of table document) and  try to insert a blank new table with one row and one column no borders  and with background colour of your choice and with your header font and then rejoin both tables
8. Edit designs or styles of tables

Hope any one of the above works